# mod_rewrite - get images from subfolder for specific HTTP Host

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have very simply situation, but I still can't make it works. My back-end controls more than one site and I need to make simple rewrite of /img/ folder to /img/subfolder/ for specific HTTP hosts.

So, from URL `www.site1.com/img/logo.svg` file will be in `/img/logo.svg`
and from URL `www.site2.com/img/logo.svg` will be in `/img/site2/logo.svg`

I have this code in .htaccess, but it throws 500 error

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site2.com
RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ img/site2/$1 [L]
```

What am I overlooking? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site2.com
> RewriteRule ^img/(.*)$ img/site2/$1 [L]
> ```

This will throw a 500 error because the `RewriteRule` *pattern* also matches the target URL, which will result in an endless rewrite loop. You need to exclude requests that have already been rewritten to `img/site2/`, or perhaps just match `img/<file>`, instead of `img/<anything>`.

For example, try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(site2)\.com
RewriteRule ^img/([^/]+\.\w{2,4})$ img/%1/$1 [L]
```

This matches `/img/logo.svg`, but not `/img/site2/logo.svg`.

The `%1` backreference contains the domain name (ie. "site2") captured from the preceding *CondPattern*. This simple saves repetition.

Comment: Thank you, works fine! Maybe I need a little pause. Thanks again, have a nice day!